# Python TimedRotatingFileHandler is logging both to previous date files and current date file

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python Flask API which is logging with TimedRotatingFileHandler to a new file every day. The thing is I founded it is logging messages to multiple files and not just the file of the current day as I expected. Not the same message to multiple files, I think it is just copying some messages to the current date file and another messages to a different previous file.

For example I have the file *rest_api_log.20231115* with the line:

*INFO - 2023-11-30 16:21:36,160 - Se ha ejecutado el método get_foo()*.

and the file *rest_api_log.20231129* with the line:

*INFO - 2023-11-30 16:20:56,153 - Se ha ejecutado el método get_foo()*.

but in the file *rest_api_log.20231130* (november 30) I have this line:

*INFO - 2023-12-01 09:44:31,322 - Se ha ejecutado el método add_foo(serial=908708ACE)*.

On the january 18 file I have traces of january 19, and on the current date (january 19) file with name *rest_api.log* I also have traces from january 19. So the traces of the same date are distributed over more than one file. I don't know if it is a problem with processes to the level of *Gunicorn* (ExecStart with 3 workers) or if I should init a logger instance again on every HTTP request. Apparently the logger is "keeping handler open" and writing to files of previous dates.

This is my api_logger.py file:

```
import logging

from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

def init_logger(level=logging.INFO):
    logpath = "logs/rest_api.log"
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s')
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(logpath, when="midnight", interval=1)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.setLevel(level)
    handler.suffix = "%Y%m%d"  
    logger.addHandler(handler) 
    logger.setLevel(level)
    return logger
```

This is an idea of how looks my main with requests:

```
from flask import request, jsonify, render_template
import logging

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

apilog = init_logger(logging.INFO)

@app.route('/foobar', methods=['GET'])
def get_foobar():
    try:
        foo = some_work()
        resp = flask.make_response(foo)
        resp = RestHeaders.add_headers_to_response(resp)
        apilog.info(api.LOG_INFO_GET_FOO)
        return resp, api.HTTP_SUCCESS
    except Exception as e:
        apilog.exception(api.LOG_ERR_GET_FOO)
        return ExceptionManager.get_foo_exceptional_response(e)
```

Maybe I should move the apilog initialization inside every method or is a thing related to server workers I don't know, or it is something wrong on the logger configuration.

**EDITED**

Ok, as @VinaySajip pointed out and is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) this appears to be a problem related with Gunicorn workers because you can't write to the same file from multiple processes in the way I have written this. Right now I have two server nodes and a minimum load of requests so I will just limit the workers to one and see if this is the source of the problem until I have time to a proper solution in multi-process scenario.

Comment: Is `init_logger()` ever called more than once within the app lifetime?

Comment: If you have multiple processes logging to the same file, you could have a problem - make sure you use the approach suggested the Python logging cookbook for mulriple-process scenarios.

Comment: @JohnGordon I checked and the init_logger() method is called three times, apparently one per Gunicorn worker. Maybe this is not the way to do this.